# Predictive editor for Rascal grammar

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to write a predictive editor for a grammar written in Rascal.  The heart of this would be a function taking as input a list of symbols and returning as output a list of symbol types, such that an instance of any of those types would be a syntactically legal continuation of the input symbols under the grammar.  So if the input list was [4,+] the output might be [integer].  Is there a clever way to do this in Rascal?  I can think of imperative programming ways of doing it, but I suspect they don't take proper advantage of Rascal's power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty big question. Here's some lead to an answer but the full answer would be implementing it for you completely :-)

1. Reify an original grammar for the language you are interested in as a value using the `#` operator, so that you have a concise representation of the grammar which can be queried easily. The representation is defined over the modules `Type`, `ParseTree` which extends `Type` and `Grammar`.
2. Construct the same representation for the input query. This could be done in many ways. A kick-ass, language-parametric, way would be to extend Rascal's parser algorithm to return partial trees for partial input, but I believe this would be too much hassle now. An easier solution would entail writing a grammar for a set of partial inputs, i.e. the language grammar with at specific points shorter rules. The grammar will be ambiguous but that is *not* a problem in this case.

   - Use tags to tag the "short" rules so that you can find them easily later: `syntax E = @short E "+";`
   - Parse with the extended and now ambiguous grammar;
   - The resulting parse trees will contain the same representation as in `ParseTree` that you used to reify the original grammar, except in that one the rules are longer, as in `prod(E, [E,+,E],...)`
   - then select the trees which serve you best for the goal of completion (which use the `@short` tag), and extract their productions "`prod`", which look like this `prod(E,[E,+],...)`. For example using the `/` operator: `[candidate : /candidate:prod(_,_,/"short") := trees]`, and you could use a cursor position to find candidates which are close by instead of all `short` trees in there.
3. Use list matching to find prefixes in the original grammar, like `if (/match:prod(_,[*prefix, predicted, *postfix],_) := grammar) ...`, prefix is your query as extracted from the `@short` rules. `predicted` is your answer and `postfix` is whatever would come after.
4. yield the `predicted` symbol back as a type for the user to read: `"<type(predicted, ())>"` (will pretty print it nicely even if it's some complex regexp type and does the quoting right etc.)

Comment: That's a tremendous answer.  Thank you very much.  I wondered whether it was possible to find out from Rascal's parser which rules were 'active' while parsing the last symbol on the input list.  Then you could determine legal continuations just by inspecting the constructors for those rules.

Comment: Yes, we've been thinking about this too and I did write an experiment doing exactly this (In the code you will find stuff about "robust" tokens ) Since we use a top-down algorithm we basically have the "call stack" available. The current implementation is bread-first non-deterministic top-down (meaning the parallel stacks are synchronized on shifting characters). The stacks can tell you where you are and what to expect next. The non-determinism generates a lot of noise, which is why our experimented stranded.

Comment: We are currently exploring another kind of parser algorithm; when this is finished we plan to look at adding partiality and recovery again which would help in producing the information for auto-complete.